# What is the meaning of frame in requestAnimationFrame in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am having hard time understanding what are [frames](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4) in JavaScript. Is frame a data structure? Is it frames as in FPS or refresh rate? Is it a fixed-time slice of window like preemptive scheduling? Also, it the [same article](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4) it says:

> rAFs aren’t throttled for you if they take too long to execute.

What does this means?

I understand how `setInterval` can cause performance issues when callbacks are long running by basically pilling up too many callback in the queue to execute. Also, What is the relation of **frame** with event loop of call stack/thread of execution?

Comment: An animation frame is...a frame of animation. So, yes - FPS - one of the frames displayed on the screen within second.

Comment: Did you look at MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @epascarello, I did read the MDN and old legacy docs on Chrome and Mozilla blog but nothing concrete.

Comment: @VLAZ Understood. So when I say `requestAnimationFrame`, is it actually like I am asking for new frame to render after everything is done or more like render as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Every code which is dedicated to an animation should be executed with `requestAnimationFrame`. When you say `requestAnimationFrame` that means: as soon as a frame is ready to be rendered, execute the callback (which should move or transform elements based on the `timestamp` parameter), and then render the frame. That allows the code which is dedicated to the animation to be run exactly at the same rate than the screen framerate.

The CPU consumption of the animation is then adjusted to what the screen can display.

An usual pattern is to call `requestAnimationFrame` recursively:

```
function render(timestamp) {
  // Move and transform things
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Comment: To do animation, I need to read latest DOM typically using `getBoundingClientRect()` function which causes layout trashing! So, if we are saying that `rAF` used just before rendering, won't reading DOM cause forced trashing and thus rendering by negating the use for `rAF` altogther? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You have to take care of reading the DOM before writing to it in order to prevent superfluous repaints.